# padding a return value from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I use this code to revieve some data from my database. The database has one column, that are numbers from 0 - 40. I get my return numbers from the database in a DIV tag. I would like to sort the numbers, so

1 - 20 is going on the left side of the div tag
21 - 40 is going on the right side of the div tag
0 is going in the middle of the div tag

I am thinking if it is possible to put a padding on some specifik numbers, or which way is the smartest to do it?

EDITED...

Thanks for the answers guys. The code is quite amateur, but I am not so good at it yet. But the return of the database is ok, except there is comming a 0 everytime. In the left handside where the numbers in the div are, that is where I want to padding some specifik numbers.

I hope that clearlifies my question a little bit?

Best Regards 
Julie

[image]

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\placing.css">
    <title>Numbers</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="topbar">
        <p>Topbar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="talraekke" id="show">
        <p>Tal</p>
    </div>
        <div class="content">
        <p>Enter The Number</p>
        <form id="myForm" action="select.php" method="post">
            <input type="number" name="numbervalue">
            <button id="sub">Save</button>
        </form>
        <span id="result"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="talraekke">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="talraekke">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// Insert function for number
function clearInput() {
    $("#myForm :input").each( function() {
         $(this).val('');
    });
}

    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#sub").click( function(e) { 
       e.preventDefault(); // remove default action(submitting the form)
       $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
       });
       clearInput();
    });
    })


// Recieve data from database
$(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#show').load('response.php')
            }, 3000);
        });
```

PHP Response from DB

```
// Return data from database
$result = $conn->query("SELECT numbers FROM numbertable");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['numbers'] . '<br>';
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting the right results from your ajax call?It looks a bit strange code to me. If I am wrong and everything works for you than please post your HTML where you wish to output your data.

Comment: Hello Franco. Thanks a lot for your answer. I just edited my question. Maybe it is more clear now? best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you should use this simple way:

```
<?php

for($i=0; $i<=40; $i++)
{
    echo '<div class="test">'.$i.'</div></br>';
}

?>
<style type="text/css">
.test{
background-color:#284062;
text-align:center;
color:#fff;
min-width:30px;
width:32px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I think that Julie wants to get the output in the columns and in a specific order

Comment: Thanks for the answer Herolind. Yes that was what I meant Franco.